# Using the same login session in a different browser by copying cookies doesn't work

Tags: authentication, web, session, cookies

I'm a CS student, and I've learned that (at least in most cases) sessions are stored in cookies, that's why you keep logged in even after a computer restart.
I wanted to see it with my own eyes, so I made a simple experiment. I just logged in a popular website (e.g. youtube, gmail, facebook, etc), and typed `document.cookie` into the the console then received the content. After that I opened a new browser, went to the same site, and paste the cookie with this command `document.cookie = ...`. I refreshed the page, but it didn't work. What am I missing? Based on my knowledge, it should work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For security, login cookies should be marked as [HTTPonly](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) which sends them with HTTP requests, but prevents them from being read by JavaScript.   Using `document.cookie` in the console isn't going to show all the cookies, especially not the secure login cookies.

To get a list of all the cookies you would have to use your browser's cookie manager that shows the HTTPonly cookies as well.